# Daily log check in unix

Tags: unix, logging

I'm trying to check an error every hour in daily log. Garbage collection is creating a file with ".hprof" extensions and I want to write a script that will find "OutOfMemoryError" error in that extension and in that day.That script will run one time in every hour. After that i want it to mail me. How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you had Googled for cron to know how to schedule a script for every hour.
edit crontab as this

```
0 * * * * <script_path> >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and for script you can use some thing like this..

```
month1=`date | awk '{print $2}'`
day1=`date | awk '{print $3}'`
year1=`date | awk '{print $6}'`
grep year1 <file>.hprof | grep month1 | grep day1 | grep OutOfMemoryError | mailx -s "report" <e-mail_addess>
```

Comment: I described you in a wrong way. There is no time value in .hprof file. So I want to compare dates with ".hprof file created date and sysdate".

Comment: I still dint get 100% what you are asking me of...<file>.hprof is created every hour or for a day